# Cannot be referenced from static context Android

Tags: android

I'm a beginner on Android, i'm creating a movie application where the user can browse the movies and search for top rated or most popular ones.
i'm using DetailsFragment to display movie details, also i'm using an expandable list view to display movie's trailers and reviews

my problem is that i get an error on this line 
listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

that says: this cannot be referenced from static context and i can't solve it by using getActivity() or DetailsFragment.this

Sorry if I'm being extremely incompetent but I searched and I couldn't understand how to fix it. Thanks.

here is DetailsFragment.java

```
package com.example.android.movies;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.android.movies.R.id.favoriteButton;
import static com.example.android.movies.R.id.iv_poster;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment{


    static Long id;
    String title, overview, poster, date;
    String vote;
    ImageView posterIV;
    TextView titleTV, dateTV, overviewTV, voteTV;
    static Context mContext;

    static ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    static ExpandableListView expListView;
    static List<String> listDataHeader;
    static HashMap<String, List<Trailers>> listDataChild;

    static ArrayList<Trailers> arrTrailers;
    static ArrayList<Trailers> arrReviews;

    ToggleButton favorite;
    private MoviesDB db;

    Trailers t;


    public static DetailsFragment newInstance() {
        return new DetailsFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // receiving intent

        Intent gIntent = getActivity().getIntent();
        Movies movie = null;
        if (gIntent != null && gIntent.hasExtra("movie")) {
            movie = gIntent.getParcelableExtra("movie");


            id = movie.getMposter_id();

            title = movie.getMtitle();
            titleTV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            titleTV.setText(title);

            date=movie.getMdate();
            dateTV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
            dateTV.setText(date);

            vote=String.valueOf(movie.getMvote());
            voteTV= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_vote);
            voteTV.setText(vote);


            overview=movie.getMoverview();
            overviewTV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_overview);
            overviewTV.setText(overview);

            poster = movie.getMposter_path();
            posterIV = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(iv_poster);
            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185".concat(poster)).into(posterIV);

            favorite= (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(favoriteButton);

        }
        favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                db.insert(id,title,poster,date, Double.parseDouble(vote),overview,t.getContent1());

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private static void settingAdapter() {
        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private static void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<Trailers>>();


        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Reviews");
        listDataHeader.add("Trailers");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), arrReviews); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), arrTrailers);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mContext=getActivity();

        new TrailersFetcher(getActivity(), id).execute();
    }

    public static void updateTrailers(ArrayList<Trailers> trailers){

        arrTrailers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <trailers.size() ; i++) {
            arrTrailers.add(trailers.get(i));

        }
        new ReviewsFetcher(mContext, id).execute();
    }

    public static void updateReviews(ArrayList<Trailers> reviews){
        arrReviews = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i <reviews.size() ; i++) {
            arrReviews.add(reviews.get(i));

        }

        settingAdapter();
    }
}
```

Comment: you cant use static context as this will cause MemoryLeakException in your app

Comment: why is it static in the first place?

Comment: Secondly you have create your own ExpandableListAdapter.. i.e Create a new Class and extend it with BaseExpandableListAdapter and then use it.. Have a look at it http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107

Comment: i already created my adapter and it works fine, my problem is here..how can i solve it ? :/

Comment: if i tried to make my methods non static.. i'm enforced to implement a bunch of methods that i don't need to

Comment: One suspicious thing in the code is - why **everything** is `private static` ? Also, when I started writing answer no comments were there ( I went away), I will update/remove accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Simlple OOP rule** - *Non-static variables/members/objects cannot be referenced in static context (methods, classes etc).*

***Why?***

Static references does not require initialization to call, so there may be cases (mostly) that normal (non-static) members/objects are not initialized and a call is made to that (static) method. This will always throw `NullPointerException` (for reference types).
So its checked at compile time that non-static reference is not made in static context.

***Solution..***

either make a `static` object of `ExpandableList`, or

remove `static` from  `private static void settingAdapter()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need so many static declarations.
modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations.

Non-static variable **this** cannot be referenced from a static context.

```
private static void settingAdapter() {
    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Just remove 'static':

1. **From Methods:**
   settingAdapter 
   prepareListData
   updateTrailers 
   updateReviews
2. **From Variables:**
   Context mContext 
   ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter 
   ExpandableListView expListView
   List listDataHeader
   HashMap> listDataChild
   ArrayList arrTrailers
   ArrayList arrReviews